# PHP preg_match not giving result after PHP7 update

Tags: php

Hi and thanks for reading.

I have been using this for a while on an old php5 running on a Windows XP box. Recently I moved everything to a php7.0 running on a linux box.

It still runs fine in the old environment but not on the new one. Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Here is the data going in;

http://192.168.0.2/test/index2.php?doing=advicepart3&from=advicepart3update&id=5096&delivered=5&delivered1&delivered3=&discount=0.00&carriage=0.00

Basically it is delivering part of an order.

```
if (preg_match("/^delivered([0-9]+)$/", $key, $matches) == 1) {
$id = $matches[1];
$sql1a = "SELECT QUANTITY, DELIVERED FROM salesitems WHERE ID = '" . $id . "' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result1a = $conn->query($sql1a);
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1a)) 
{
} 
else 
{
print "Error: " . $sql1a . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn) . " Contact support";
}
if ($result1a->num_rows > 0) {
while($row1a = $result1a->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $ordered = $row1a['QUANTITY'];
    $alreadydelivered = $row1a['DELIVERED'];
}
}
$updatedelivered = $alreadydelivered + $value;
if ($updatedelivered > $ordered)
{
    $updatedelivered = $ordered;
}
$outstanding = $ordered - $updatedelivered;
$sql = "UPDATE salesitems SET DELIVERED = '". $updatedelivered ."', OUTSTANDING = '". $outstanding ."'  WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
{
} 
else 
{
print "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn) . " Contact support";
}
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: this could be a case issue; \*NIX is case-sensitive in everything as opposed to Windows. Use php's error reporting.

Comment: Since we cannot run your code, could you tell us what the arguments are and what happens? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Fred-ii- Full error reporting turned on but shows no error.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 
delivered=5
delivered=1
delivered=3
Before, these happily updated into the database.

Answer (score 0):

No wonder there wasn't an error - there wasn't anything wrong with it. Problem was the php I wrote had a problem. Each of the delivered should have had a number appended to them (taken from a query) but the query wasn't reading properly.

Thank you for making me look elsewhere.